# Проблема с axios в React

Tags: reactjs, axios

Ввожу команду **npm i axios**
Прописываю функцию:

```
async function fetchPosts() {
    const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    console.log(response.data)
  }
```

А также кнопку, чтобы выполнить функцию:

```
<button onClick={fetchPosts}>GET POSTS</button>
```

А при попытке запустить код выскакивает ошибка:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint] 
src\App.js
  Line 22:28:  'axios' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: А вы импортировали библиотеку в проект?

Comment: А как это сделать? import что именно?

Comment: Ну что то вроде `import axios from 'axios';` или `import { axios } from 'axios';`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Заработало!